# ng-click to ng-scroll for pagination in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-click

Here is a Plunker [Pagination in Angular](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview)
where pagination is done on the basis of clicking next page or previous or numbers using angular event "ng-click" which  calls function `setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)` from the file `'dirPagination.tpl.html'`.

I want to know if I can  call the function `setCurrent()` using scroll instead of click such that `setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)` will be called and when I scroll till the top of the page the function  `setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)` will be called.

Comment: Have you ever heard about ngInfinityScroll? There seems to be no problem to develop something like that. but it would be counter intuitive to go back you you hit the top of the page. By the one, if the last page has 1 record, you would display it and, at the same time, go back - because you would be at the top of the page.

Comment: Yes I have used ngInfinityScroll but in ngInfinityScroll when I scroll down I get the next page data and I can also see the previous page data as well which make the page heavier but in dirPagination it renders just the amount of data wanted in single page.